# Custom animation with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

What is the correct way to use a custom [GlideAnimation](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/331/com/bumptech/glide/request/animation/GlideAnimation.html) when loading an image? I expected the `animate()` method to take a `GlideAnimation` but that doesn't seem to be the case. Is this just for internal use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's currently just for internal use. Feel free to make a pull request that opens it up if you're interested. It's going to be more accessible in the upcoming v4 release.